# Approximating a function with sums of gaussians

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, approximation-algorithms

For an application I have to approximate a continuous (and hopefully smooth) positive even function that decays at infinity with a sum of sums of gaussians, preferably orthogonal ones.

That is, a function $$f(x)|f(x)=f(-x),\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$$ I'd like to approximate with $$\Sigma_ng_n(x)|g_n(x)=\Sigma_ka_{nk}e^{-(x/s_{nk})^2}$$ so that $$\int g_ng_m=\delta_{mn}$$ and $$lim_{n\to\infty}\Sigma_ng_n(x)=f(x)$$

In addition, I would prefer for each $g_n$ to have bounded, eh, "conditioning number": $$\forall n \frac{\max_k(s_{nk})}{\min_k(s_{nk})}<C$$ where $C$ does not depend on $n$.

---

One way to go about it is to set $$y=e^{-x^2}$$ then approximate $$h(y):=f(x)$$ with Chebyshev polynomials over $y$, and then change variables back.

However, I don't like this solution very much because it limits $s_{nk}$ to square roots of integers and therefore unlikely to be optimal. In addition, the above "conditional number" won't be bounded.

---

Since I'm doing this for an application the speed of convergence matters very much. Could you suggest another method for producing the above approximation or a reference that considers such problems?

---

EDIT: the above seems to be related to [Radial basis function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function) approximations.

Comment: How can gaussians, being positive nonvanishing functions, be orthogonal?

Comment: @IgorRivin, Gaussian cannot be, but $g_n$ are sums of Gaussian, with coefficients $a_{nk}$ that don't have to be nonnegative.

Comment: The span of Gaussians is dense in the space of even Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Density refers to the usual topology on the space of Scwartz functions. See Lemma 2.2 in  http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/bessel2.pdf

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question somewhat...

Comment: Liviu, that link no longer works and I couldn't dig up the pdf by Googling.

Answer (score 2):

> Approximate a function with a sum of sums of gaussians, preferably orthogonal ones.
>   ... the above seems to be related to Radial basis function approximations.

Indeed, you could use an RBF interpolant at chosen centers as an approximation for your function. Then apply a Gram–Schmidt orthogonalization to construct linear combinations of the RBFs that are orthogonal with respect to a given inner product.